# Discord.js second-accurate updating timer in embed

Tags: timer, discord.js, embed

I'm looking for a way to create a second-accurate countdown timer within an embed. I tried editing it every second, which didn't work at all (good at first, then edits would pile up and go all at once). I heard from a friend who knows a major bot developer that it was possible, but never got a reply on how to do it. If anybody has any solutions, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're getting ratelimited. Calling the API to do something every second is API Spam.

Comment: @Elitezen yeah i figured, just wanted to know if there was a way to do this without spamming the api.

Comment: Sadly not, a message edit will always require a call to the API

Comment: @Elitezen alright, i'll just update it in bigger intervals. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting this answer so I can close the question, there's no way to make what I wanted work.